# Django doesn't send password rest email

Tags: python, django, forgot-password

I'm trying to make a password reset form and I added next urls:

```
path('reset-password/', password_reset, name='reset_password'),
path('reset-password/done/', password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

Also I added next lines to my `settings.py` file:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'my_gmail_email@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'my_gmail_email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_gmail_email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_gmail_password'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

I get all forms correctly and when I type in email of a user it shows that email with reset password link was sent but it doesn't.

Comment: Does the Gmail account you're sending through have 2-factor auth enabled? If so, you'll need to disable it.

Comment: No, it doesn't have 2 factor auth

Comment: have you checked spam?